# Keras - force one particular weight to be positive

Tags: python, optimization, keras, neural-network

I know that it is possible to force the weights of one layer to be positive using Keras, as documented [here](https://keras.io/constraints/) .

However I do not find any documentation on how to force one particular weight (not the whole vector) to be positive. Is it possible using Keras ?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out something similar.  I'd like to be able to constrain weights from a single input to be positive according to this paper: https://papers.nips.cc/paper/1358-monotonic-networks.pdf